# How can I get code coverage results in my Aurelia app using karma?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, karma-coverage, aurelia

I created an Aurelia app using the Aurelia CLI (`au new`) and would like to set up code coverage (preferably with *karma-coverage*, but if that's not possible I'll use whatever).

I first `npm install karma-coverage --save-dev` then copy the `test.js` task over to a `cover.js` (so that I can run `au cover`).

### cover.js

```js
import {Server as Karma} from 'karma';
import {CLIOptions} from 'aurelia-cli';
// import project from "../aurelia.json";

export function cover(done) {
  new Karma({
    // This is the same as what's in karma.conf.js after running
    // Except I added the 'src\\**\\*.js' part
    files: [
      'scripts\\vendor-bundle.js',
      {pattern: 'test\\unit\\**\\*.js', included: false},
      'test/aurelia-karma.js',
      'scripts\\app-bundle.js',
      'scripts\\materialize-bundle.js',
      {pattern: 'src\\**\\*.js', included: false}
    ],
    configFile: __dirname + '/../../karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: !CLIOptions.hasFlag('watch'),
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    //logLevel: 'debug',
    preprocessors: {
      // [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id],  // Is this actually needed? Nothing changes if I add or remove this...
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel', 'coverage']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      includeAllSources: true,
      reporters: [
        {type: 'html', dir: 'coverage'},
        {type: 'text'}
      ]
    }
  }, done).start();
}

export default cover;
```

This... gets me somewhere?

[image: Console output of <code>au cover</code>]

But I don't think the tests are being linked to the individual src files (they're instead being linked to `app-bundle.js`).

**Is there any way to get code coverage at the src file level (i.e. not bundle level) for an Aurelia app?**

## Other Files of Interest

### app.js

```js
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

### karma.conf.js

```js
"use strict";
const path = require('path');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');

let testSrc = [
  { pattern: project.unitTestRunner.source, included: false },
  'test/aurelia-karma.js'
];

let output = project.platform.output;
let appSrc = project.build.bundles.map(x => path.join(output, x.name));
let entryIndex = appSrc.indexOf(path.join(output, project.build.loader.configTarget));
let entryBundle = appSrc.splice(entryIndex, 1)[0];
let files = [entryBundle].concat(testSrc).concat(appSrc); console.log(files);

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: [project.testFramework.id],
    files: files,
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id]
    },
    'babelPreprocessor': { options: project.transpiler.options },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    // client.args must be a array of string.
    // Leave 'aurelia-root', project.paths.root in this order so we can find
    // the root of the aurelia project.
    client: {
      args: ['aurelia-root', project.paths.root]
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, but it required a lot of under-the-hood modifications =\

First I had to install the following packages

```
npm install karma-coverage --save-dev
npm install karma-requirejs --save-dev
npm install babel-plugin-istanbul --save-dev
```

## aurelia_project/tasks/cover.js

This is based on `test.js`.

- Add `requirejs` to the list of `frameworks` (from the *karma-requirejs* package)
- Add the individual src/test files (with `included: false`) as well as `test/aurelia-karma-cover.js`, which does the actual `require`ing of test files.
- Modified `aurelia-karma.js` into `aurelia-karma-cover.js` to not include `/test/unit/setup.js` (it was giving me trouble with *aurelia-browser-pal* dependencies)
- Remove `"coverage"` from src file preprocessing (*babel-plugin-istanbul* will now handle instrumentation of code - see statement at the end for details).

```js
import {Server as Karma} from 'karma';
import {CLIOptions} from 'aurelia-cli';
import project from "../aurelia.json";

export function cover(done) {
  new Karma({
    configFile: __dirname + '/../../karma.conf.js',
    frameworks: [project.testFramework.id, 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      {pattern: 'src\\**\\*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test\\unit\\**\\*.js', included: false},
      // This file actually loads the spec files via require - it's based on aurelia-karma.js
      // but removes setup.js and its dependencies
      'test/aurelia-karma-cover.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
      'src/environment.js',
      'src/main.js',
      'src/resources/index.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    singleRun: !CLIOptions.hasFlag('watch'),
    coverageReporter: {
      includeAllSources: true,
      reporters: [
        {type: 'html', dir: 'coverage'},
        {type: 'text'}
      ]
    }
  }, done).start();
}

export default cover;
```

## test/unit/aurelia-karma-cover.js

Just change `var allTestFiles = ['/base/test/unit/setup.js'];` to `var allTestFiles = [];` to avoid *aurelia-pal-browser* dependency errors.

## aurelia_project/aurelia.json

Add `"istanbul"` to the `transpiler.options.plugins` list if using *babel-plugin-istanbul*.

** Without `babel-plugin-istanbul`, code coverage works on post-transpiled code, which adds boilerplate that can't really be tested. This allows you to get to 100% code coverage ;)*

Comment: can you get more details on this please? My tests aren't executed at all. And, do you still use "au test" now?

Comment: @Sergiu, this is all the detail there is. And I use `au cover` now.

Comment: Could you please share all files changes, i think something i am missing its not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

From your terminal screenshot, it looks like you're getting coverage on your individual files `src/app.js` (12.5%), `src/environment.js` (0%) and `src/main.js` (12.5%) in addition to the bundle file. It has to do with that extra line you added including the files that are in `src/`.

I suspect that if you go to your coverage directory and view that in the browser, you'll see more detailed results.

I'm not sure about the Aurelia app specifically, but to get individual file coverage, you want to have your tests run against your original files instead of the bundled version and you want that same path to your original files to also be in preprocessors.

```
files: [
    ...
    'src/**/*.js',
    'path/to/tests/*.spec.js'
    ...
],
preprocessors: {
    'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
}
```

This pattern (which you've done) is what tells Karma to load the individual files, and include them in the coverage. At this point, I wouldn't bother loading the bundled application code since you have all the raw stuff being loaded.

Also be sure to load them in the order they're probably bundled in so that you can be sure Karma can initialize the app in the first place.

```
files: [
    'src/app.js',
    'src/environment.js',
    'src/main.js'
]
```

And if you are putting your specs named `myTest.spec.js` next to the files they test, you can use `src/!(*.spec).js` to make sure that you are including application code without the tests.

Comment: This got me started in the right direction, but transpiling, requirejs, and aurelia in general made it much more complicated than this =\ I found a way though, I'll update with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@lebolo These were the adjustments I had to make to get things working here:

**aurelia_project/tasks/cover.js**

Included a constant to vendors path in the beginning of cover function:

```
const VENDORS_PATH = __dirname + '/../../node_modules/';
```

Used VENDORS_PATH to include libs I depend on, in files:

```
files: [
  {pattern: VENDORS_PATH + 'moment/min/moment.min.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'test/unit/**/*.js', included: false},
  'test/aurelia-karma-cover.js'
]
```

Included test files in preprocessors:

```
preprocessors: {
  'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
  'test/unit/**/*.js': ['babel']
}
```

**test/unit/aurelia-karma-cover.js**

Change the way url is built in `requirejs.load` function:

`url = '/base/' + url;` => `url = ['/base', root, url].join('/');`

Included one more function to config requirejs paths and calling it after `patchRequireJS()` call:

```
  function configRequire() {
    var VENDORS_PATH = '../node_modules/';

    requirejs.config({
      paths: {
        'moment': VENDORS_PATH + 'moment/min/moment.min'
      }
    });
  }
```